# VBA search for value in a column after specific pattern

Tags: string, vba

I have input data like this:

```
gen,N,,,GONGD,,,N,,,KL,0007bd,,,,,,,,TAK,
gen,N,,,RATEC,,,N,,,KP,0007bc,,,,,,,,TAZ,
kap,N,,,EBFWE,N,,,,,,,,,KP,002bd4,,,KP,123000,,,,,N,,,,P
kap,N,,,ST,WEIT,E3,EBFWEI,,,KP,002bd2,N,,,,,,KP,002bd3,,,,,,,Z,MG00,,,,,N,,,,P
```

One line is in one column. First I need to know I am in a row starting with "kap" and then I need to save 6 characters (or numbers) after first ",KP," as "Variable1" and save also the 6 chars or numbers after the second ",KP," as "Variable2". Please help me, I am hopeless.

Expected result: Var1 = 002bd4, Var2 = 123000 for the first "kap" row. Var3 = 002bd2, Var4 = 002bd3

I have tried this to know I am in "kap" starting line:

```
Sub Find()
Dim rFoundAddress As Range
Dim sFirstAddress As String
Dim x As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
    Set rFoundAddress = .Find("kap,*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAddress = rFoundAddress.Address
        Do


            Set rFoundAddress = .FindNext(rFoundAddress)
        Loop While Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing And _
            rFoundAddress.Address <> sFirstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

THANKS!

Comment: what has that "msz,*" your searching for to do with "kap" and "KP"?

Comment: Look at `Split` or the better way, regular expressions, split by comma first to find the first element, then split by "KP" maybe for the number as the first element

Comment: @user3598756 my mistake, I have edited it. Thank you.

Comment: form your narrative I'd expect: _Var1 = 002bd4, Var2 = 002bd5 for the first "kap" row_ , instead of _Var1 = 002bd4, Var2 = 123000_. How's it actually?

Comment: @user3598756 I am sorry I have made mistake again. Now it should be correct. First line - Var1, Var2, Second line - Var3, Var4 etc. And of course there are always only 2 KP per line and lower number of Var means the first KP from the left. I am sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub Find()
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim vals As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        Set rFound = .Find("*kap,*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                vals = Split(Split(Split(rFound.text, "KP")(1), ",")(1) & "," & Split(Split(rFound.text, "KP")(2), ",")(1), ",")
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

where at every row you'l get `vals` array storing the two wanted values in that row

Comment: I cant format it properly. But I have used this code. Your one is probably also working. Anyway, thanks for help!
`Dim WrdArray() As String
                Dim text_string As String
                text_string = rFoundAddress
                WrdArray() = Split(text_string, "KP,")
                strg = Left(WrdArray(1), 6) & vbNewLine & Left(WrdArray(2), 6)
                MsgBox strg`

Comment: you are welcome. BTW, I don't get what formatting issues you can have: my code returns an array (`vals`) of two elements, so that you can retrieve its elements as `vals(1)` and `vals(2)`, and then do what you want with them

Comment: no I meant that I cant format the reply comment correctly :D code is working, thanks again

Comment: I have updated my code and my problem. Please have a look if you have time [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527069/vba-search-save-and-replace-by-rows-according-to-conditions)

Comment: hi, I had a look at your new post and I must say that unfortunately people there gave you wrong advice: it _is_ a new issue and therefore it is to be posted in a _new_ question. Make that new post and if you'll give me a word I'll certainly have a look at it.

Comment: thank you. Now it is posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527069/vba-search-save-and-replace-by-rows-according-to-conditions)