# VBA: Search, save and replace by rows according to conditions

Tags: vba, replace, error-handling

I have an input like this:

```
gen,N,,,GONGD,,,N,,,KL,0007bd,,,,,,,,TAK,
gen,N,,,RATEC,,,N,,,KP,0007bc,,,,,,,,TAZ,
kap,N,,,EBFWE,N,,,,,,,,,KP,002bd4,,,KP,123000,,,,,N,,,,P
kap,N,,,ST,WEIT,E3,EBFWEI,,,KP,002bd2,N,,,,,,KP,002bd3,,,,,,,Z,MG00,,,,,N,,,,P
```

I have a code like this:

```
Sub Find()
Dim rFoundAddress As Range
Dim sFirstAddress As String
Dim x As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
    Set rFoundAddress = .Find("kap,*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing Then
        sFirstAddress = rFoundAddress.Address
        Do
            Dim WrdArray() As String
            Dim text_string As String
            Dim i As String
            Dim k As String
            Dim num As Long
            text_string = rFoundAddress
            WrdArray() = Split(text_string, "KP,")
            i = Left(WrdArray(1), 6)
            k = Left(WrdArray(2), 6)

            Columns("A").Replace What:=i, _
                        Replacement:=k, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False

            Set rFoundAddress = .FindNext(rFoundAddress)
        Loop While Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing And _
            rFoundAddress.Address <> sFirstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do:
Find all lines starting with "kap" and save 6 chars/int after first "KP" as i and 6 chars/int after second "KP" as k. Then search the whole data-set (hundreds of rows in column A) if they contain string i and if yes, then replace it for string k. And to loop this. So it will do the same with another line starting with "kap". The code gives me error message: Subscript out of range when it comes to "Columns("A")..." for the second time. Can you help me please?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Yes we can help you, but this is an extension of [your post of yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508377/vba-search-for-value-in-a-column-after-specific-pattern), so please move your modifications there. Thanks.

Comment: @PierreChevallier Hi! What is the common way to do this? Just edit my question from yesterday with this one? Or as a new comment or how? Thank you

Comment: Comment on your previous post stating what is the error you get, if it is provided by a user's answer, reply in the comment section of the user so she/he can help you.

Comment: @PierreChevallier ok it is there. I will delete this question in 5 minutes. Thanks

Comment: The issue is re-opened here after advice of another user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to make all searched string occurrences the same ("kap,*")

you don't want to modify (via `Replace()`) the range you're looping through

so collect all needed replacements in an array while looping through the range and then loop through the array and make the replacements

like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find()
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim nKap As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)
        nKap = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Cells, "kap,*") '<--| count the occurrences of "kap,*"
        If nKap > 0 Then
            ReDim vals(1 To nKap) As Variant '<--| array that will collect all find/replace couples
            nKap = 0
            Set rFound = .Find("kap,*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            sFirstAddress = rFound.Address
            Do
                nKap = nKap + 1
                vals(nKap) = Split(Split(Split(rFound.text, "KP")(1), ",")(1) & "," & Split(Split(rFound.text, "KP")(2), ",")(1), ",") '<--| store the ith couple of find/replace values
                Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
            Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAddress

            For Each val In vals '<--| loop through values to be replaced array
                .Replace What:=val(0), _
                        Replacement:=val(1), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, _
                        ReplaceFormat:=False
             Next val
        End If


    End With
End Sub

Function GetValues(txt As String) As Variant
    If InStr(txt, "KP") > 0 Then GetValues = Split(Split(Split(txt, "KP")(1), ",")(1) & "," & Split(Split(txt, "KP")(2), ",")(1), ",")
End Function
```

Comment: Hi! This would do not exactly what I want. Why: If I run your code it will replace everything at once. What I need to do is to find KP1, KP2 and then replace it everywhere. And then in the next step to search for another KP1, KP2 (lets call it KP3, KP4) and replace it also everywhere. Therefore it can be replaced also in already replaced "KAP" from the first round. So my KP2 can be replaced by KP4 in the second round of the code. Thats why I need it to be "loop in a loop". I dont know if I explained it sufficiently :/

Comment: I don't get you. My code doesn't do all replacements at once, but it loops through every couple and makes the corresponding replacement one after another. Have you tried running the code and compare its results to a "manual" replacements as you'd do it?

Comment: @EduardDindoffer, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi I am sorry I need to solve another issue. I will come to it tomorrow and check your code again. Thanks for help

Comment: Hi! So I have tried it. I got an error: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: Which line is throwing it?

Comment: rFound.Address was not set. I had to update LookAt:=xlWhole to xlPart. Now it is running for 20 minutes already. It has more than 50 000 lines to check. Is there any way to speed up the code?

Comment: as for the `rFound.Addres` issue, I fixed some typos where I didn't use the same string `"kap,*"` in all the code: see edited code. As for the time issue this is a new one and you should make a new post. And since it'd be about an optimization of a working code you'd better post it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). While since my solution answered your _original_ question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128136/discussion-between-eduard-dindoffer-and-user3598756).